# Booting hangs at "Checking battery...."

Tags: power-management

Ubuntu 9.04 (JAUNTY JACKLOPE version)Installation Guidance REQUESTED.

I am a quite new user (more proper to say “..a learner”) of Ubuntu. I am a Sr. citizen.
Please guide and help me in the matter mentioned below. My system is a Pentium III, 804 MHz processor, Asus CUSL-2 Mother board,  512MB RAM SD TWO hard-disks 80 GB & 20 GB. 
I installed Ubuntu 9.04 on a separate HD of 20 GB using CHIP's Live DVD to install.

It is JAUNTY JACKLOPE version. It is successfully installed. On starting the system, it also displayes booting options as under:

- Ubuntu 9.04 kernel 2.6.28 – 11 genuine
- Ubuntu 9.04 kernel 2.6.28 – 11 genuine (Recovery Mode)
- Ubuntu 9.04 memtest86+
- Other Operating System:
- Microsoft Windows XP Professional

If Win.XP is selected, it starts. But if Ubuntu 9.04 option is given, it starts booting, checks all parameters and gives [OK] to all but stops at "Checking battery...." it stops and after 2 to 3 flickers the monitor screen becomes blank/dark... nothing comes on it. I have tried with all the three options as displayed above. The result is the same- i.e. nil.

Please help me in the matter and provide guidance in a very simple detailed way and oblige. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu? I am also curious about your video card. Can you run `lspci | grep VGA` in a terminal and post the results? Is the 20 GB hard drive a flash drive? I only ask because someone else reported this issue when using a flash drive [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1154375).

Comment: This issue also affects ubuntu 11.04 Alpha release.

Comment: Do you still have the problem. Have you found how to solved the problem or considered accepting an answer that solves your problem (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

Hey,
It sounds like you just installed Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty. Therefore, this implies that you know how to install Ubuntu the regular way with the graphical desktop CD/DVD installer.
However, you said you used  the "CHIP" live DVD.
I am not sure what CHIP or their live DVD is. Is www.CHIP.de a site for a German computer magazine or something?

Well regardless, assuming you just installed Ubuntu from this DVD, there is one very big problem. Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty is no longer supported by Ubuntu. This means it will no longer receive security or bug fix updates/patches. The bottom line of this is that if you use 9.04, your it will be vulnerable to any new malware (viruses) or hacking attempts that have been developed since Ubuntu 9.04's support stopped last month (it was supported for 1.5 years.) The support life-times are explained in the 1st google result for the search term "ubuntu wiki releases".

Fortunately, the solution to the lack of support is the same solution that will likely make your laptop work with Ubuntu. The solution is to install a newer version of Ubuntu that is supported for a while. Ubuntu 10.10 maverick is the latest version and will be supported until April 2012, but your system is fairly old so I'd recommend ubuntu 10.04 lucid which is supported until April 2013 (and partially supported until April 2015.) Since Ubuntu 10.04 is a newer version/release it is very likely to include a fix for the bug that prevents 9.04 from starting up.

To download Ubuntu 10.04 and then install it, follow this link:
http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download .
Select "Ubuntu 10.04 - Long Term Support" and then "32-bit, recommended". Then hit download. On this same page you will see instructions for burning the 10.04 CD and installing it. Once it is burnt, it will be the same basic steps that you used to install 9.04 Jaunty. However, you will want to chose to install 10.04 to your entire 20GB hard drive that Ubuntu 9.04 jaunty is on, deleting the old Ubuntu 9.04 install in the process. (Remember, you only want to do this if you do not have any data on the Ubuntu 20GB drive as it will be lost! (Which I presume because I presume you just installed it.) If you do have any data on the Ubuntu drive, copy it over to the windows drive, or a CD, or a usb drive, etc.)

Of course, I presume you have data on your 80GB windows drive so make sure windows (the NTFS parition) on that drive is not touched.)

Again, assuming you just installed 9.04, the steps above to install 10.04 are what I strongly recommend. However we may be able to make your 9.04 install work by installing all bug-fix/security updates for it from the recovery mode. This is assuming you have broadband (fast) internet connection rather than dial-up, which would greatly complicate and slow down things. Here are the steps:

1. Make sure you are connected to the internet (via a router or whatever) over a wired ethernet connection, as opposed to wireless. (Wired ethernet is the usual way for a desktop.) If you are on wireless, tell me and I'll give you a lot more instructions.
2. Turn on your computer and at the boot menu, select: Ubuntu 9.04 kernel 2.6.28 – 11 genuine (Recovery Mode)
3. Ubuntu should start up into recovery mode, getting past the error you saw before. Once you see a blue menu with several text options, select "Drop to root shell prompt" (it may be named something similar.)

4: At this root shell prompt, (it's a command prompt, like the old days of dos, but way more powerful) enter these commands:

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade

(You have to enter these commands exactly. You will see a lot of text scroll by for each step, and the 2nd one may take a few hours on your computer. The 2nd one will prompt you to continue, hit Y for yes, then enter.) If you don't run into any errors, that means your system is updated successfully.)

5: Assuming it worked correctly, you enter the following command to reboot:

shutdown -r now

6: When the computer gets back to the boot menu, you should see Ubuntu with a higher kernel number as the default. Select that and see if it starts up successfully without running into the bug you saw before.

I apologize for this message being so long but it was necessary for the seriousness of the problem and to make things easily understood yet comprehensive. Ask me if you have any questions at all.

Comment: Whoops, I just read that you said you tried all 3 options at the boot menu, which includes the recovery mode. So while I still strongly recommend reinstalling with Ubuntu 10.04 (or maybe 10.10), I have a replacement for the 2nd method I mentioned.

Comment: Whoops, got cut off there:
Anyway, to continue:
At the boot menu, with the 1st option selected, hit e . you will then see 4 lines. Go to the one with "quiet splash" on its end, and hit e. Delete "quiet splash" from the end and hit enter. Then hit b to boot.
You should then see either Ubuntu start up successfully, or text with more info (hopefully a helpful error message.)
You can try this with the 2nd boot option (recovery mode) too.